# Best Algorithm to encrypt password

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I want to encrypt the password & store the encrypted value in MySQL database. What algorithm is the best way to go for encryption in Java?

For each user, I've userid, useremail field as well & for all these users, I need algo to encrypt password.

Note: I should be able to decrypt the password as well, since one of our support page shows the password only to support team (Legacy page that cannot be removed).

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this is not a good fit for this Q&A. We help with programming questions. Also, the standard is to HASH passwords, which is a one way function. Often it is considered unsafe to encrypt them.

Comment: 10 seconds of googling found the solution for your problem here: http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html

Comment: Encryption is not the way to go..start with salted hashes...

Comment: Usually hashing is used.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question. Yes, it's good to point out that under normal circumstances hashing is the preferred choice, but the OP stated that he has a legitimate reason for storing the passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are standard algorithms for encrypting passwords. You can use
PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC from BouncyCastle.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1, sample code, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too quickly. That's a hashing algorithm. You want the encryption one.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed???? As mentioned I need the encryption & not hash & the admin still closed this question??

Comment: I think people have a kneejerk reaction to storing passwords in the DB. In general, it's considered bad practice with respect to security of the system.

Comment: But this is not the password that is used for login to web site or something critical...I cannot put all those details here due to legal reasons. What if I want to encrypt the userid? What algo should be used? I should have mentioned user instead of password field!

Comment: Is there any encryption available within in Java itself without using third party library?

Comment: There are, but they're not very good. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/pbe_key_derivation.shtml